# How to show exactly one selected item among all as dropdown title in angular js dropdown multiselect?

Tags: angularjs, multi-select, dropdown

Currently when I set dynamicTitle=true. it is showing all the selected items as in the below image.
[image]

I want it to show only item. I searched at
[source](http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/#/) but could not find how to do it.

There is an option to select maximum number of elements, but I should be able to select any number of elements but show only one element as title.

and element

```
<div title={{model.Base.currentRecord.value.Code.display}} ng-dropdown-multiselect="" ng-class="choosen" options="locations" selected-model="myModel"  extra-settings="settings" translation-texts="{buttonDefaultText: 'Select Districts'}" style="display:table" class="pull-right"></div>
```

`

```
                scrollableHeight: '300px',
                closeOnBlur: true,
                dynamicTitle: true,
                scrollable: false,
                displayProp: 'label',
                idProp: 'id',
                externalIdProp: 'id',
                enableSearch: false,
                selectionLimit: 0,
                showCheckAll: true,
                showUncheckAll: true,
                closeOnSelect: false,
                buttonClasses: 'btn btn-default',
                closeOnDeselect: false,
                groupBy: $attrs.groupBy || undefined,
                groupByTextProvider: null,
                smartButtonMaxItems: 1,
                smartButtonTextConverter: angular.noop
```

`

Can somebody help me out through an example?

Answer (score 0):

Just from reading the Docs on their site, I believe the property you are looking for is:

```
smartButtonMaxItems : 1

/HTML
<div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="example13data" selected-model="example13model" extra-settings="example13settings"></div>

//JS
$scope.example13model = [];
$scope.example13data = [
    {id: 1, label: "David"},
    {id: 2, label: "Jhon"},
    {id: 3, label: "Lisa"},
    {id: 4, label: "Nicole"},
    {id: 5, label: "Danny"}];

$scope.example13settings = {
    smartButtonMaxItems: 3,
    smartButtonTextConverter: function(itemText, originalItem) {
        if (itemText === 'Jhon') {
        return 'Jhonny!';
        }

        return itemText;
    }
};
```

Comment: No, that is not what I wanted. I want the title should contain exactly one selected item to make the dropdown size fixed. "Smart Button Text" feature, defines the maximum amount of items to "on the button".

Comment: I'm not following, that is exactly what you asked, for and your image up there has 3 selected items
If you set this property only one will show: smartButtonMaxItems : 1
What title are you reffering to?

Comment: I tried it, but it's still showing more than 1 element in the dropdown as shown in image.

Comment: Dude, it's an image, it can't open into a drop-down, so I still don't know what you are talking about. Please open a new Angular plunkr and add the script and your code: https://rawgit.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/master/src/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect.js